# Trigger fails on a primary key with two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, logging, triggers, postgresql-9.3

Just experimenting with triggers. I am trying to build logs (generated by a trigger on an `INSERT` action). This attached trigger (in [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f8949/1/0)) works fine if the key is a single column - but it fails if it is two combined columns (in this case - `id` & `md`).

The error is:

[image]

I keep fiddling with this - but I'm not sure I see what the fix is...

Comment: Perhaps you should show the definition of the `log.history` table? It seems likely that it has no column `pkey_id`.

Comment: @CraigRinger - I don't think that is the problem. I create the table in the SQL Fiddle - lines 5-19. .. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f8949/1/0

Comment: Your SQLFiddle does not produce the error you show above.